# How can I make embedded resource in taskRun using fabric8::tekton-client

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8, tekton-pipelines

I'm using fabric8::tekton-client(v4.7.1) to make "taskRun" object.

below is a sample code to make taskRun.

```
public TaskRun createTaskRun() {
    TaskRun tr = new TaskRunBuilder()
    .withApiVersion("tekton.dev/v1alpha1")
    .withNewMetadata()
        .withName("sample-taskrun")
        .endMetadata()
    .withNewSpec()
        .withServiceAccountName("build-bot")
        .withTaskRef(
            new TaskRefBuilder().withName("s2i").withApiVersion("tekton.dev/v1alpha1").withKind("Task").build()
        )
        .withNewInputs()
            .addNewParam()
                .withName("BUILDER_IMAGE")
                .withValue(new ArrayOrString("docker.io/centos/nodejs-8-centos7"))
            .endParam()
            .addNewResource()
                .withNewName("source")
                    .withNewResourceSpec()
                        .withType("git")
                        .addNewParam("url", "https://github.com/sclorg/nodejs-ex")
                    .endResourceSpec()
                .endPipelineResourceBinding()
            .endResource()
        .endInputs()
        .withNewOutputs()
            .addNewResource()
                .withName("image")
                .withNewResourceSpec()
                    .withType("image")
                    .addNewParam("url", "192.168.6.82:5000/nodejs-ex")
                .endResourceSpec()
            .endResource()
        .endOutputs()
    .endSpec().build();

    return tr;
}
```

In this code,

> .withName("source")

makes an error: "error: cannot find symbol".

But latest tekton pipeline(v0.10.1) spec allows embedded resources and also their name field in taskRun.

How can I declare embedded resources in taskRun using fabric8::tekton-client(v4.7.1)?

Comment: I think Fabric8 Kubernetes Client's model is right now at v0.9.0 . I think we updated model few months ago. But these tekton and knative orgs are moving so fast ;-) . Could you please file an issue to upgrade tekton model to latest version?

Comment: @RohanKumar Thanks for the comment. I think the problem is on tekton-client api. The latest version of tekton-client doesn't have "withName()" and "withNewResourceSpec()" functions for defining resources, so I can't define new resources for taskRun. Instead, I found "withNewPipelineResourceBinding()" function. Is this function is new function for defining taskRun resources?

Comment: Yeah, maybe. We generate Pojos from go structs and builders using sundrio library. So this field might have been introduced in last updated version.

Comment: However, when I use "withNewPipelineResourceBinding()", I succeed to compile, but   runtime error occurs. **unknown field "pipelineResourceBinding".** I tried these with tekton model v0.10.1 and v.0.9.0 both. Is there any documents or examples of the api?

Comment: You can find examples in https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/tree/master/extensions/tekton/examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/tekton/api/examples

Comment: Examples in the link only show how to define pipeline resources. and documents of tekton-client (https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.fabric8/tekton-client/4.7.1/overview-summary.html) only shows list of functions, not mentioning what the function is for. Is there any other documents with description of functions?

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have much documentation atm. Would appreciate if you could contribute since you're playing with tekton-api :-)